# regex how can i find only two whitespace and a number?

Tags: regex, string, text, numbers, whitespace

hi i want to use regular expression with this kind of string, but i can't figure out how to do this. i try to use

\s\s5 to find this string. but i also find some string like \s\s\s\s5

```
123
4567
5
 5
  5
     5
```

you can see that there are some structure that we i need to deal with.
is there anyway that i can match the

```
<whitespace><whitespace>5
```

but not to match the string with more than two whitespace?

```
<whitespace><whitespace><whitespace><whitespace>5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor your regular expression to the start of the line (`^`):

```
^\s\s5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate that you're looking for a full line:

```
^\s\s(\d+)$
```

where the `^` marks the start of the line and the `$` the end of the line.

It also depends which language you're working in, because Java's `java.util.regex.Matches` has a `find()` method that will match inside a String, and a `matches()` method that will match an entire string.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression language where \s is a whitespace:

```
[^\s]\s\s5
```

(this will find any instance of 5 which follows 2 whitespaces, i.e. "abc  5" would match; not sure if this is your question or you are asking about beginning of the string, others have responded to that)